# Arduino serialporta com C#

Tags: c#, arduino

Pego a informação passada pela porta serial do meu arduino com esse codigo:

```
cnx.Open();
    string carro = cnx.ReadLine();
    textBox1.Text = carro;
    cnx.Close();
```

Gostaria de saber se seria possivel eu dar dois print no arduino e enviar dois valores para a porta serial com  informações diferentes? e como eu faria para pegar essas duas informações com o readline no meu programa c#?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o seu problema? Eu estava pensando em modificar minha resposta, mas seria legal ter um _feedback_ seu, antes.

Comment: jovem, dá continuidade aos seus tópicos por favor, em outro, respondi o que poderia te ajudar e você apagou a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode escrever em um Print apenas, e separar por um caractere comum, por exemplo um ';' aí ficaria assim:

o arduino envia: "ABC-1234;GM;CELTA;BRANCO"

no c#:

```
string linha = cnx.ReadLine();
string[] valores = linha.Split(';');

string placa = valores[0]; //ABC-1234
string marca = valores[1]; //GM
string modelo = valores[2]; //CELTA
string cor = valores[3]; //BRANCO
```

pelo que entendi, é isso que você precisa

Answer (score 3):

Você poderia ler as informações da porta serial com o `ReadLine()`, mas você precisaria criar um **listener** para que toda vez que tivessem dados disponíveis na porta, eles fossem lidos.

A sugestão é que você use o evento [`DataReceived`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx), que será chamado quando houverem dados a serem lidos*.

Para teste, você pode fazer upload do programa `SerialEvent` do Arduino:

[image: Abrindo o projeto SerialEvent no Arduino]

E com o seguinte código de exemplo, você pode enviar e receber dados pela porta serial:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ArduinoSerial
{
    class ArduinoSerial
    {
        private static SerialPort portaSerial = new SerialPort("COM3",
            9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // quando há dados na porta, chamamos dadosRecebidos
            portaSerial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(dadosRecebidos);

            // criar a conexão
            portaSerial.Open();

            // mantendo o programa rodando
            while (portaSerial.IsOpen)
            {
                // o que escrevermos no console, vai pra porta serial
                portaSerial.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        // dadosRecebidos imprime a informação de volta no console
        static void dadosRecebidos(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string dados = sp.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(dados);
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: Saída do Programa]

> No programa `SerialEvent` do Arduino, você verá que para enviar dados
>   pra porta serial, é usado `Serial.println(inputString);`. Modificando
>   o programa, e substituindo `inputString` pelo que você quiser, você
>   poderá enviar dados diferentes para o seu programa em C#.

*Na documentação o indicado, na verdade, é que se use [`BytesToRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread(v=vs.110).aspx) para saber se há dados a serem lidos.

Fontes:
[How to Read and Write from the Serial Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243070/how-to-read-and-write-from-the-serial-port)
[Server Client send/receive simple text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182751/server-client-send-receive-simple-text)
[C# Serial Port Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29018539/1579771)